# moles: making sealed internal classes visible to

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest, moles

I need a help as I am very new to moles, I have the following code:

```
namespace A.BusinessLayer
{
sealed class AManager
{
void Method1(object obj){
// do something

}

}

public class B
{
void Method1(object obj){
if some thing{
AManager a=new AManager();
a.Method1();
}

}
}
}
```

Now I am creating Unit Tests for the above classes as below (wondering whether this could even be possible):
**Explanation:** When B.Method1 is called I simply wan't to check whether A.Method1 was called from the implemetation, this is what I am simply expecting this code to test.

```
namespace A.Tests
{
 class BTest
{
void Method1Test(){
//I need something like
A.BusinessLayer.Moles.MAManager t=new A.BusinessLayer.Moles.MAManager();
t.Method1=(obj)=>{
Assert.IsTrue(true);
};
B=new B();
B.Method1();

//Assert.IsTrue(true);

}

}
}
```

I have added following attributes to AssemblyInfo class of A.BusinessLayer project as :

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("A.BusinessLayer.Moles")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("A.BusinessLayer.Tests")]
```

**Problem** is I cannot see any Moles for AManger class?

Any help even to improve my approach will be appriciated.

**Update:** I see class AManager in *moles.xml file, but cannot see it in the A.BusinessLayer.Moles dll through object browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head with monitor for some time, it finally started to work. Here is what I did:

You need to clean the test project and then build it again

Hope this helps to some one suffering from the same problem.

As for the approach is considered I am using the below code:

```
namespace A.Tests
{
 class BTest
{
void Method1Test(){
bool isMethodInvoked=false;
A.BusinessLayer.Moles.MAManager.AllInstances=()=>{
isMethodInvoked=true;
};

B=new B();
B.Method1();

Assert.IsTrue(isMethodInvoked, "Method is not invoked");

}

}
}
```